# How to delete outliers from a QQ-plot graph made with ggplot()?

Tags: r, ggplot2, outliers, quantile

I have a two dimensional dataset (say columns x and y). I use the following function to plot a QQ-plot of this data.

```
# Creating a toy data for presentation

df = cbind(x = c(1,5,8,2,9,6,1,7,12), y = c(1,4,10,1,6,5,2,1,32))

# Plotting the QQ-plot

df_qq = as.data.frame(qqplot(df[,1], df[,2], plot.it=FALSE))

ggplot(df_qq) + 
   geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y), size = 2) + 
   geom_abline(intercept = c(0,0), slope = 1)
```

That is the resulting graph:

[image]

My question is, how to avoid plotting the last point (i.e. (12,32))? I would rather not delete it manually because i have several of these data pairs and there are similar outliers in each of them. What I would like to do is to write a code that somehow identifies the points that are too far from the 45 degree line and eliminate them from df_qq (for instance if it is 5 times further than the average distance to the 45 line it can be eliminated). My main objective is to make the graph easier to read. When outliers are not eliminated the more regular part of the QQ-plot occupies a too small part of the graph and it prevents me from visually evaluating the similarity of two vectors apart from the outliers.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: check `coord_cartesian()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a CRAN package, [referenceIntervals](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/referenceIntervals/index.html) that uses Cook's distance to detect outliers. By applying it to the values of `df_qq$y` it can then give an index into `df_qq` to be removed.

```
library(referenceIntervals)

out <- cook.outliers(df_qq$y)$outliers
i <- which(df_qq$y %in% out)

ggplot(df_qq[-i, ]) + 
  geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y), size = 2) + 
  geom_abline(intercept = c(0,0), slope = 1)
```

[image]

**Edit.**

Following the OP's comment,

> But as far as I understand this function does not look at 
>   the relation between x & y,

maybe the following function is what is needed to remove outliers only if they are outliers in one of the vectors but not in both.

```
cookOut <- function(X){
  out1 <- cook.outliers(X[[1]])$outliers
  out2 <- cook.outliers(X[[2]])$outliers
  i <- X[[1]] %in% out1
  j <- X[[2]] %in% out2
  w <- which((!i & j) | (i & !j))
  if(length(w)) X[-w, ] else X
}
```

Test with the second data set, the one in the comment.
The extra vector, `id` is just to make faceting easier.

```
df1 <- data.frame(x = c(1,5,8,2,9,6,1,7,12), y = c(1,4,10,1,6,5,2,1,32))
df2 <- data.frame(x = c(1,5,8,2,9,6,1,7,32), y = c(1,4,10,1,6,5,2,1,32))

df_qq1 = as.data.frame(qqplot(df1[,1], df1[,2], plot.it=FALSE))
df_qq2 = as.data.frame(qqplot(df2[,1], df2[,2], plot.it=FALSE))

df_qq_out1 <- cookOut(df_qq1)
df_qq_out2 <- cookOut(df_qq2)
df_qq_out1$id <- "A"
df_qq_out2$id <- "B"
df_qq_out <- rbind(df_qq_out1, df_qq_out2)

ggplot(df_qq_out) + 
  geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y), size = 2) + 
  geom_abline(intercept = c(0,0), slope = 1) +
  facet_wrap(~ id)
```

[image]

Comment: But as far as I understand this function does not look at the relation between x & y, for instance if df was `df = cbind(x = c(1,5,8,2,9,6,1,7,32), y = c(1,4,10,1,6,5,2,1,32))` I would not want to mark (32,32) as an outlier and I would not want to get rid of it. Yet, cook.outliers function still returns 32 as an outlier.

Comment: @ElifCansuAkoğuz Maybe the function in the edit is what you want. See if it is and then say something.